# Does video tag html5 slow my webpage or is it heavy if I have many videos in video tags?

Tags: video, html5-video

```
<video width="400" controls>
  <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

I want to insert many videos in my website, but I am afraid that it will make it slow even if they are not playing.

Comment: How much is many videos?

Comment: 5 or 6, is like in a feed so it could be none or more depending on what people upload